# Webpack style!css!sass loaders

Tags: html, css, sass, webpack

I'm newbie in Sass so possible  this is my mistake. Anyway let me describe the problem

***html file***

```
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">LinkedIn</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Rss</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Yahoo</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I would like to create a simple list of links for some social network.
For build i'm using *webpack* with css-loader sass-loader and style-loader.

```
...
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style',"css", "sass"]
      }
    ]
  }
 ...
```

Works well while i didn't try to add pictures for the each *li* element in my

***sass file***

```
$icons:(facebook, google, linkedin, rss, twitter, yahoo);
@each $item in $icons{
  .#{$item} {background: url('./images/#{$item}.png') no-repeat;}
}
```

And i go an error

> Unexpected token ILLEGAL You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type.

All images are exist in this folder.

What am I doing wrong? I just want to build a simple url for the backgroung images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to add a url-loader:

```
{ test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
```